# Spring-Boot Quartz Job is not running

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron, quartz-scheduler

I just started to create Quartz Scheduled Jobs in a dynamic way. So there is a QuartzConfig class where I create a `SchedulerFactoryBean`, `JobDetailFactoryBean` and `CronTriggerFactoryBean`. Wherein the Job and CronTrigger beans are prototype ones.

```
@Configuration
public class QuartzConfig {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;;

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean quartzScheduler(){
        SchedulerFactoryBean quartzScheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        quartzScheduler.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
        quartzScheduler.setSchedulerName("job-scheduler");
        AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
        jobFactory.setApplicationContext(context);
        quartzScheduler.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
        return quartzScheduler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "prototype")
    public JobDetailFactoryBean getJobBean(){
        JobDetailFactoryBean bean = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        bean.setJobClass(DailyJob.class);
        bean.setGroup("daily-group");
        bean.setName("daily-name");
        bean.setBeanName("daily-name");
        bean.getJobDataMap().put("daily", "daily");
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "prototype")
//    @Lazy(value = true)
    public CronTriggerFactoryBean getCronTriggerBean(String cron){
        CronTriggerFactoryBean bean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
        bean.setCronExpression(cron);
        bean.setJobDetail(getJobBean().getObject());
        bean.setGroup("daily-group");
        return bean;
    }
}
```

In my Controller class I want to create the jobs by request. I autowire `SchedulerFactoryBean` to set the quartz trigger to the bean.

```
@Controller
public class JobController {

    @Autowired
    SchedulerFactoryBean quartzScheduler;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;;

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/job/create/daily")
    public String dailyJob(){
        CronTriggerImpl cron = (CronTriggerImpl) context.getBean("getCronTriggerBean","30 * * ? * MON-FRI");
        Trigger[] triggers = { cron };
        quartzScheduler.setTriggers(triggers);
        return "dailyJob";
    }
}
```

Everything works without creating an error and the `Job` and the `Trigger` are set to the `quartzScheduler` (see it in debug mode). But the Job is never running. What do I miss?

And dont to forget, there is a class which implements `Job`:

```
@Component
public class DailyJob implements Job{

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("Daily Job runs!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see your triggers in the `TRIGGERS` table? If yes, what state do they have?

Comment: @ledniov you mean a triigers table in DB? I dont use one at the moment. All is setting up by context and will destroyed after shutdown.

Comment: Can you try injecting `Scheduler` instead of `SchedulerFactoryBean` and use `scheduler.scheduleJob(cron)`?

Comment: @ledniov tried it. Got this exception. `org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: The job (daily-group.daily-name) referenced by the trigger does not exist.`  Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

```
@Controller
public class JobController {

    @Autowired
    private Scheduler scheduler;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/job/create/daily")
    public String dailyJob() throws SchedulerException {
        JobDetail jobDetail = context.getBean(JobDetail.class);
        Trigger cronTrigger = context.getBean(Trigger.class, "30 * * ? * MON-FRI");

        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, cronTrigger);

        return "dailyJob";
    }
}
```

You have to use `Scheduler` instead of `SchedulerFactoryBean` as the purpose of the latter is to create the actual scheduler that will operate on jobs.

Also if you use `scheduler.scheduleJob(cron)` it woun't schedule the job because it isn't in the job store yet, so you'll need to create a job using it's details and associate cron expression with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try addding "@EnableScheduling" to your configuration

Comment: sadly, it does not change anything. I have a similar project using quartz (not dynamic and working) where I dont have/need this annotation. Any other idea?